# Toggle content close all of them

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I've created a toggle for content, pretty easy, show and hide the content but when I press a button show or hide all of the contents no just the content next to the pressed button. I have this problem also when I use a ngFor :|

Here is the Plunker if you want to take a look
https://plnkr.co/edit/ncAQog?p=preview

Thanks guys for your help :)

### App component

```
import {Directive, Input, HostBinding} from 'angular2/core';


@Directive({selector: '[collapse]'})
export class Collapse {
    // style
    @HostBinding('style.height')
    private height:string;
    // shown
    @HostBinding('class.in')
    @HostBinding('attr.aria-expanded')
    private isExpanded:boolean = true;
    // hidden
    @HostBinding('attr.aria-hidden')
    private isCollapsed:boolean = false;
    // stale state
    @HostBinding('class.collapse')
    private isCollapse:boolean = true;
    // animation state
    @HostBinding('class.collapsing')
    private isCollapsing:boolean = false;

    @Input()
    private set collapse(value:boolean) {
        this.isExpanded = value;
        this.toggle();
    }

    private get collapse():boolean {
        return this.isExpanded;
    }

    constructor() {
    }

    toggle() {
        if (this.isExpanded) {
            this.hide();
        } else {
            this.show();
        }
    }

    hide() {
        this.isCollapse = false;
        this.isCollapsing = true;

        this.isExpanded = false;
        this.isCollapsed = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.height = '0';
            this.isCollapse = true;
            this.isCollapsing = false;
        }, 4);
    }

    show() {
        this.isCollapse = false;
        this.isCollapsing = true;

        this.isExpanded = true;
        this.isCollapsed = false;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.height = 'auto';

            this.isCollapse = true;
            this.isCollapsing = false;
        }, 4);
    }
}
```

### Component toggle example

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Collapse} from './collapse.component';

/*Angular 2 Collapse Example*/
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app', 
    template:`
                <h3>Angular 2 Collapse HTML Content</h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                        (click)="isCollapsedContent = !isCollapsedContent">Show / Hide Content (Toggle collapse)
                </button>
                <hr>
                <div [collapse]="isCollapsedContent" class="card card-block card-header">
                  <div class="well well-lg">
                   HTML content goes here !
                   <b>bold text</b> <br>
                   <span>this is a collapse example</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <h3>Angular 2 Collapse HTML Content</h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                        (click)="isCollapsedContent = !isCollapsedContent">Show / Hide Content (Toggle collapse)
                </button>
                <hr>
                <div [collapse]="isCollapsedContent" class="card card-block card-header">
                  <div class="well well-lg">
                   HTML content goes here !
                   <b>bold text</b> <br>
                   <span>this is a collapse example</span>
                  </div>
                </div>



             `,
    directives: [Collapse],
})
export class Angular2Collapse  {
    //collapse content
    public isCollapsedContent:boolean = false;
    //collapse image (example)
    public isCollapsedImage:boolean = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understood the goal, but here is something for you.

In order to keep the state (expanded/collapsed) of multiple items, you need array of states. Each button should be associated with corresponding collapsible section.

Also you have too many states, one `isExpanded` should be sufficient:

```
isExpanded: Array[boolean];
```

Actually, I'd recommend going through this tutorial: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/03/27/building-a-zippy-component-in-angular-2.html

It shows the development of a similar component called **Zippy**

Comment: Thanks Mate, I saw the links and information about the zippy and looks like it is a div container for both action (click button + content toggle), In this case it doesn't work for me :( thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can try to provide [(ngModel)]="togglBtnVal" for your button and provide the same ngModel as *ngIf="togglBtnVal" for elements to be hide/show based on the button click.